# Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons - already removed from php.ini

Tags: php, shell-exec

I removed shell_exec from the disable_functions section in my php.ini script, and then proceeded to restart apache. But error as shown as the title still persists.

Anyone have any idea what causing this?

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the right `php.ini`? double check with `phpinfo()` function

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to confirm that Raptor helped answer my question.

Doing a phpinfo() printout I found that the disable_functions section still had the shell_exec issue there.

The problem was I had a server management software that required that I edit files from there and no the system directly. So adding back the clause and removing it helped to solve the issue. (To sync up the changes from the management system and the server system).